# .each confusing behavior for click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very confused by the foreach behavior of javascript,
I'm using the .each of jquery to set some event listeners:

```
$(".xRibbonMenu").each(function(index){
    ribbonMenu= new RibbonMenu($(this));
    $(this).find(".xRibbonTab").each(function(index){
        ribbonMenu.tabs.push($(this));
        $(this).click(function(){

            ribbonMenu.div.find(".xRibbonTabActive").removeClass("xRibbonTabActive");
            $(this).addClass("xRibbonTabActive");

            ribbonMenu.div.find(".xRibbonContentActive").removeClass("xRibbonContentActive");

        });
    });
    $(this).find(".xRibbonContent").each(function(index){
        ribbonMenu.contents.push($(this));
    });
    RibbonMenus.push($(this));
});
```

but if the event is invoked, the ribbonMenu seems always to be the one of the last run of the loop.
I don't know this behavior form any other language.
So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add a `var` before `ribbonMenu` : `var ribbonMenu = new RibbonMenu($(this));`

Comment: ... if you don't, then `ribbonMenu` will be a global variable, and therefore shared across all iterations.

Comment: oh such easy I am ashamed:)
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Karl mentioned, you need to add `var` to your variable, like so:

```
var ribbonMenu= new RibbonMenu($(this));
```

The reason for this is because in javascript, when you don't explicitly declare a variable to be local, it is global; you need to be very careful about this, since it's one sure way to get bugs, as you know ;)